# Getting records where attributes have certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a project with a model Person, a person has many Pets, and a Pet and a Boolean attribute Mammal, Id like to be able to retrieve all people whose have at least one pet who is a mammal, but I'm not sure how to do this, I've tried:

```
Person.includes(:pets).where(pets: {mammal: true})
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What is the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In `where` clause there should be the actual name of the database table - in your case its `pets`:

```
Person.joins(:pets).where(pets: { mammal: true }).group('persons.id')
```

Comment: Sorry the question was mistyped, this is how I have my query, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2320239 I've edited it according to the edit (i did not notice, you wanted only persons, that have at least one pet)

Comment: @user2320239 you want to use `joins` for INNER JOIN, and includes for LEFT OUTER, which means, `joins` returns only persons with pets, whereas `includes` would return all persons, with those, that do not have pets at the end of the list

Comment: Thanks for the replies, though this seems to not work, Person.joins(:pets).where(pets: { mammal: true }).count returns 14, whereas Person.count returns 12, obviously the number of people with mammal pets has to be less than or equal to the number of people

Comment: @user2320239 add `.group('persons.id')` to the end of my query

Comment: @user2320239 did `.group('persons.id')` do the thing? (I mean, it did, but have you got a moment to test it :D)

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

`Person.where id: Pet.where(mammal: true).pluck('distinct person_id')`